# WordPress - Missing SideBar and Footer

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Excuse my ignorance, I am very new to the web scene. I am missing a sidebar and footer on my custom theme. I was able to get the background images to appear for the header and content, but not for the footer and sidebar. I have followed several tutorials, researched to both ends of the internet and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

I am attempting to create a layout that consists of a header, content and right sidebar. I really don't want anything in my side bar from WordPress. I am going to put the site navigation and login there, but I would like the background to show up! I will post the basic code below and give the link to my site [here](http://www.itssimplydesign.com). Thanks in advance!

**index.php**

```
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php
        /* Run the loop to output the posts.
         * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
         * called loop-index.php and that will be used instead.
         */
         get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );
        ?>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #container -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<title><?php
/*
 * Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.
 */
global $page, $paged;

wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

// Add the blog name.
bloginfo( 'name' );

// Add the blog description for the home/front page.
$site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
    echo " | $site_description";

// Add a page number if necessary:
if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
    echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyten' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php

if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) )
    wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );

    wp_head();
?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="wrapper" class="hfeed">
<div id="header">
    <div id="masthead">
             .......
    </div><!-- #masthead -->
</div><!-- #header -->

<div id="main">
```

**sidebar.php**

```
<div id= "sidebar" class="widget-area" role="complementary">

</div><!-- #sidebar -->
```

**footer.php**

```
</div><!-- #main -->

<div id="footer" role="contentinfo">

</div><!-- #footer -->

</div><!-- #wrapper -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
/*
Theme Name: Mod Theme
Theme URI: http://www.itssimplydesign.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mod_theme/
Description: My First Theme
Version: 1.0
Author: Jason
Author URl: http://www.itssimplydesign.com
*/

/* =Layout
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

/*
LAYOUT: Header, Content and Sidebar
DESCRIPTION:
*/

body {
background-color: #e6e9Df;
}

#container {
float: left;
margin: 0 -240px 0 0;
width: 100%;
}

#header {
background: url(http://www.itssimplydesign.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mod_theme/images/background_main_01.png) no-repeat;
width: 1000px;
height: 332px;

}

#sidebar {
background: url(http://www.itssimplydesign.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mod_theme/images/background_main_03.png) no-repeat;
float: right;
clear: right;
overflow: hidden;
width: 300px;
}

#content {
background: url(http://www.itssimplydesign.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mod_theme/images /background_main_02.png) no-repeat;
min-height: 668px;
width: 700px;
float: left;
}

#footer {
clear: both;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yo haven't code anything in footer. Please add something and chek it.

Comment: Very good point. The footer works. The sidebar is my major concern. Any ideas why the background image isn't showing?

Comment: same way sidebaris working too..plz check it

Comment: I think your background is coming properly.. isnt so ?

Comment: No, there are three background files. One for the header, which is showing at the top. One for the content, which is showing on the left. And there is a third, which should be the sidebar. It SHOULD appear under the gray strip in the header and to the right of the content. It shows up under media in page info, but not on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have applied background on the content but nothing is there for the footer.

You can either change to styling of the footer in your css, or you can put

```
<div id="footer" role="contentinfo">

</div>
```

in #container too. Then, it would all be included in the same div and the background would apply too.

Similarly, you can include the sidebar like that, in the **container** only.

Comment: Sorry, should have explained better. There are three background files. The footer actually doesn't have a background file, yet. The files that I have now are the header, which is showing at the top. One for the content, which is showing on the left. And there is a third, which should be the sidebar. It SHOULD appear under the gray strip in the header and to the right of the content. It shows up under media in page info, but not on the page.

Comment: You were correct sir. Just needed to pay more attention to my styles. Thanks for the pointing me in the right direction.